# Make SELECT subquery COUNT the total subscribers of a subscriber

Tags: sql, postgresql, node-postgres

I trying to create a query that counts the total subscribers of a subscriber. It currently looks like this:

```
await this.queryInstance.query(
'SELECT all_users_subbed_to.* , (SELECT COUNT(??????)) AS subscribers_sub_count
FROM 
 (SELECT publisher_id, subscriber_id, u2.username 
 AS username, u2.user_photo AS user_photo 
 FROM subscribers s 
 INNER JOIN users u 
 ON (u.id = s.subscriber_id) 
 INNER JOIN users u2 ON (u2.id = s.publisher_id) 
 WHERE subscriber_id = ($1) 
 LIMIT 20 
 OFFSET ($2)) 
AS all_users_subbed_to;'
,
 [currentUserId = 80, offset]   
 );
```

The FROM CLAUSE AKA `all_users_subbed_to` is WORKING correctly and displays a ALL the subscribers the current user has. The data comes back as this:

```
"subscribedToCurrentUser": [
        {
            "publisher_id": 84,
            "subscriber_id": 80,
            "username": "supercoookie",
            "user_photo": "profile-pic-for-supercoookie.jpeg"
        },
        {
            "publisher_id": 88,
            "subscriber_id": 80,
            "username": "GERPAL1",
            "user_photo": "profile-pic-for-GERPAL1.jpeg"
        }
    ]
```

The issue I am having is getting the total subscriber counts for the list of those subscribers. I need to use the subscribers publisher_id ie `all_users_subbed_to.publisher_id` and get their total subs (using COUNT) from the subscribers table. I would like to create a new column called have `subscribers_sub_count` that contains that total.
Any ideas?
It should look like this:

```
"subscribedToCurrentUser": [
        {
            "publisher_id": 84,
            "subscriber_id": 80,
            "username": "supercoookie",
            "user_photo": "profile-pic-for-supercoookie.jpeg",
            "subscribers_sub_count": 3
        },
        {
            "publisher_id": 88,
            "subscriber_id": 80,
            "username": "GERPAL1",
            "user_photo": "profile-pic-for-GERPAL1.jpeg",
            "subscribers_sub_count": 70
        }
    ]
```

The subscribers table looks like this: [image]

Comment: Please update your question with plain text for the extract of the subscribers table, and with a more complete sample of data so that to understand how to get `"subscribers_sub_count": 3` and `"subscribers_sub_count": 70` in the expected result.

Comment: @Edouard "subscribers_sub_count": 3 and "subscribers_sub_count": 70 are only example numbers. I wanted to convey that they should be the total subs counts for those users and that they should be different depending on the data. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it. It just needed a WHERE clause that used data from `all_users_subbed_to`

```
await this.queryInstance.query(
'SELECT all_users_subbed_to.* , 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM subscribers s2 WHERE s2.publisher_id = all_users_subbed_to.publisher_id) AS subscribers_sub_count AS subscribers_sub_count
FROM 
 (SELECT publisher_id, subscriber_id, u2.username 
 AS username, u2.user_photo AS user_photo 
 FROM subscribers s 
 INNER JOIN users u 
 ON (u.id = s.subscriber_id) 
 INNER JOIN users u2 ON (u2.id = s.publisher_id) 
 WHERE subscriber_id = ($1) 
 LIMIT 20 
 OFFSET ($2)) 
AS all_users_subbed_to;'
,
 [currentUserId = 80, offset]   
 );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
await this.queryInstance.query(
'SELECT all_users_subbed_to.*, COUNT(all_users_subbed_to.id) AS subscribers_sub_count
FROM 
 (SELECT publisher_id, subscriber_id, u2.username 
 AS username, u2.user_photo AS user_photo 
 FROM subscribers s 
 INNER JOIN users u 
 ON (u.id = s.subscriber_id) 
 INNER JOIN users u2 ON (u2.id = s.publisher_id) 
 WHERE subscriber_id = ($1) 
 LIMIT 20 
 OFFSET ($2)) 
AS all_users_subbed_to;'
,
 [currentUserId = 80, offset]   
 );
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  It helped me think of the solution.

Comment: You're welcome mate. Glad you figured it out.